# can't send post request from reactJs using Axios to Django restframework

Tags: django, reactjs

I'm new to `ReactJs` and am trying to do post request to my Django backend server, Get request works great as expected. But post returns an error `(403) Forbidden` ,, here is my code :

```js
        axios.post('my_url', {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'my_auth_string'
            }, body: {
                'type':'in',
                'amount':'123'
            }
        }).then(res =>{
            console.log(res)
        })
```

**NOTES**

- The endpoint accepts post request, as it works as expected when I
  send the request using flutter.
- Am using BASIC auth, can this be a    problem with `axios` ?

Comment: Does your Django endpoint accept POST requests?

Comment: Yes, it works  perfectly when I send the post request form my flutter application

Comment: maybe you need a csrf_token or exempt the view function concerned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's happen when you don't add csrf token to your post request headers like this:

```
headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}',
        'Authorization': 'my_auth_string'
    }
```

Comment: And how to generate the csrf_token with axios

Comment: you don't generate it. each time you send a request django save csrf_toke in session you just use it an send it to your api

Answer (score 0):

Create a file as csrftoken.js and add below code

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  }
  
  var CSRF_TOKEN = getCookie('csrftoken');
  
  export { CSRF_TOKEN };
```

import the token in your required file

```
import { CSRF_TOKEN } from ".csrftoken.js";
```

do axios POST request then

```
axios.post(url, data, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
        }
      }).then().catch(()
  };
```

Better add session auth also with your project